# removePlayer should remove the correct player, not just the first one

Tags: javascript, html, css

Clicking on each `exit` button should remove each video, but only one video is being removed. To reproduce, click on the 1st blue play button, next, click on the exit button. `console.log("removePlayer");` says it is removed.

Do the same thing for the next video player. Click on the play button, then click on the exit, but nothing occurs unless the first video is playing.

```js
function addPlayerHandler(evt) {
  const play = evt.target;
  play.closest(".wrap").player = {};
  play.disabled = true;
}

function removePlayerHandler(evt) {
  const el = evt.target;
  const container = el.closest(".container");
  const wrapper = container.querySelector(".wrap");
  if (wrapper.player) {
    return removePlayer(wrapper);
  }
}

function removePlayer(wrapper) {
  wrapper.querySelector(".play").disabled = false;
  delete wrapper.player;
  console.log("removePlayer");
}

for (let curtain of document.querySelectorAll(".curtain")) {
  curtain.querySelector(".play").addEventListener(
    'click',
    addPlayerHandler,
  );
  curtain.querySelector(".exit").addEventListener(
    'click',
    removePlayerHandler,
  );
}
```

```css
.curtain {
  border: solid;
}

.play[disabled]::after {
  content: " - Now Playing";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="curtain">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="video"></div>
      <button class="play">Play</button>
    </div>
    <button class="exit" type="button">Exit</button>
  </div>

  <div class="curtain">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="video"></div>
      <button class="play">Play</button>
    </div>
    <button class="exit" type="button">Exit</button>
  </div>

  <div class="curtain">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="video"></div>
      <button class="play">Play</button>
    </div>
    <button class="exit" type="button">Exit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This part of the code would need to be changed to something else. I think this part of the code needs to be changed to work properly.

```
  function removePlayerHandler(evt) {
    const el = evt.target;
    const container = el.closest(".container");
    const wrapper = container.querySelector(".wrap");
    if (wrapper.player) {
      return removePlayer(wrapper);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What other information do you need? Everything I said is accurate.

Comment: Is anything in my question not accurate at all? That part of the code is broken.

Comment: You need to include your (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code here, in your question (linking to a live demo is lovely, but that's a bonus; if the code isn't here then your question will still be closed as "needing debugging details"), because that way we can reproduce your problem (on this site) without having to go look for the code elsewhere to copy and paste it back here in an answer. In addition to that provided link, please also read the "*[ask]*" guidance.

Comment: @C.BoyntonGlick Since this is an HTML/JavaScript question, you can use the Stack Snippets button (the page with the `<>`) to make the demo.

Comment: YouTube can't be viewed on stackoverflow.

Comment: @C.BoyntonGlick Yes it can. Also, that wouldn't matter for your question.

Comment: Videos can't be viewed, all that can be seen is a black screen.

Comment: @C.BoyntonGlick Does your demo require people to play the videos? Your question seems to be about making the exit buttons work. (Please simplify your demo by removing / changing bits until it _still works_ but is smaller. See [mcve] for some advice.)

Comment: Can't get smaller or else it will break, it was last over 3000 characters before. I made it as small as possible.

Comment: @C.BoyntonGlick It can get smaller. If I have time, I'll show you how in a bit. (In the meantime, keep trying! It's how you learn.)

Comment: You understand what the issue is I am referring to right? Should I provide a link to a demo code where remove player works without an issue?

Comment: @C.BoyntonGlick Yeah, I understand the issue. You did a good job identifying the problematic section. While I fix your question, maybe you could explain why you think this part is the problem?

Comment: It works perfectly fine in the demo code:https://jsfiddle.net/dpc1x5nw/ where the html I think is set up differently from this code I am working on here.

Comment: "It works perfectly fine in the demo code:jsfiddle.net/dpc1x5nw" - you maybe should have shared this before.

Comment: As can be seen in the demo code I provided, every time the exit button is clicked, the video is removed.

Comment: How do I fix the code I am currently working on?

Comment: @C.BoyntonGlick I've edited your question, by deleting all the code that wasn't related to the problem. Can you spot it, now?

Comment: When you get a chance can you take a look at this please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74407318/exit-button-on-page-2-should-remove-any-of-the-players

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const container = el.closest(".container");
const wrapper = container.querySelector(".wrap");
```

Let's look again at your HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="curtain">
    <div class="wrap">
      ...
    </div>
    <button class="exit" type="button">Exit</button>
  </div>

  <div class="curtain">
    ...
    <button class="exit" type="button">Exit</button>
  </div>

  <div class="curtain">
    ...
    <button class="exit" type="button">Exit</button>
</div>
```

Starting at a button, go up to the nearest `.container`, then go down to the first `.wrap`. What do you reach?

I think the problem's in this line:

```js
const container = el.closest(".container");
```

Is going all the way up to `.container` correct, or is there a closer parent you could pick?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249556/discussion-on-answer-by-wizzwizz4-removeplayer-should-remove-the-correct-player).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in `const wrapper = container.querySelector(".wrap");` you are always getting the first `.wrap` element.

For the documentation:

> The `Document` method `querySelector()` returns the first `Element` within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. — [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

One way to fix it could be:

1. Get the button clicked
2. Get the parent element of that clicked button that has `wrap` class
3. Do whatever you want with it (remove the video or whatever)

Comment: How do I do that, can you show me those ways?

Comment: The same way it was working in the demo code: https://jsfiddle.net/dpc1x5nw/ When the exit button is clicked, the video gets removed.

Comment: Good answer. The demo code opens a new page/element where only the element is selectable. The rest of the code where `removePlayer` appears is the same. You basically have only one element to select in the demo.

Comment: What is the best way for me to fix the issue, what would get changed in the code? Can I see an edited code where it is working?

Comment: One way could be to give each button a different ID and query this using getElementById . @arnau do you agree? Is this what you meant by your point 1?

Comment: Those 3 different ways, could you provide additional detail on each of them? How each would be done in the code?