# Trying to make gradient see-through to place an image behind it

Tags: css, background-image, gradient, transparent, linear-gradients

Where I am be able to place an image behind it and be able to see it.

Would the gradient be able to be written a different way where transparent would work?

How do I, or, how am I able to set background to transparent, and for that to be able to work in the code?

Would using mask-image or clip-path be able to work here to make it see-through?

or maybe a different way?

What am I supposed to do or change in my code to be able to set black to see-through and for it to work?

Right now the gradient image looks like this:

[image]

When `--color-b: black;` is set to transparent, I should see this image:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/8sQi6Tu.png]

Example of what I am trying to achieve:

SVG Version: https://jsfiddle.net/h8q352mg/

[image]

Why is this so difficult to do?

What will work?

How do I change the black color here to see-through?

That is all I am trying to do in the code, make the black see-through.

I keep trying different things and the colors keep blending in with each other.

Does anyone on here know how to do this so that the colors don't blend in with each other?

Since the body color is green, that is the color I should see in place of the black, when black is set to transparent.

https://jsfiddle.net/e39mub8L/

```
:root {
--color-a: #1155cc;
--color-b: black;
--color-c: #1155cc;
--color-d: black;
}
```

```css
:root {
  --color-a: #1155cc;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: #1155cc;
  --color-d: black;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: green;
  padding: 50px 8px;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-b) 10px,
      #0000 10px 160px,
      var(--color-b) 160px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-c) 15px,
      #0000 15px 155px,
      var(--color-c) 155px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-d) 20px,
      #0000 20px 150px,
      var(--color-d) 150px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-a) 25px,
      #0000 25px 145px,
      var(--color-a) 145px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-b) 30px,
      #0000 30px 140px,
      var(--color-b) 140px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-c) 35px,
      #0000 35px 135px,
      var(--color-c) 135px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-d) 40px,
      #0000 40px 130px,
      var(--color-d) 130px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-a) 45px,
      #0000 45px 125px,
      var(--color-a) 125px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-b) 50px,
      #0000 50px 120px,
      var(--color-b) 120px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-c) 55px,
      #0000 55px 115px,
      var(--color-c) 115px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-d) 60px,
      #0000 60px 110px,
      var(--color-d) 110px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-a) 65px,
      #0000 65px 105px,
      var(--color-a) 105px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-b) 70px,
      #0000 70px 100px,
      var(--color-b) 100px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-c) 75px,
      #0000 75px 95px,
      var(--color-c) 95px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-d) 80px,
      #0000 80px 90px,
      var(--color-d) 90px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
  background-size: 165px 165px;
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.container:hover .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.container:hover .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-left">
  </div>
  <div class="panel-right">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Behind the black is more blue. The issue is that there is an opaque color behind the black; it won't make the green come through. You are trying to achieve a Photoshop erase layer effect using CSS gradients. Probably the easiest solution is changing the black to the green when needed, or look into polygon shapes and go from there.

Comment: Is there a solution that would work like using mask-image or clip-path to make it see-through?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This background consists of a stack of 165px solid squares, with varying sized holes in the middle. You can see this when you build it up layer by layer, starting from the end of the list which is the bottom gradient in the stack (the lowest z-index, if you like). The bottom-most layer is a solid black square. The layer above that is a solid orange square with a small hole in the centre. The layer above that is a solid blue square with a slightly larger hole in the centre.

So if you set one particular layer to transparent, that simply results in the layer beneath becoming more visible. The background never shows through any part of any square.

[image]

```css
:root {
  --color-a: black;
  --color-b: red;
  --color-c: blue;
  --color-d: orange;
}

body {
  background: #ffffcc;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

div {
  width: 165px;
  height: 165px;
}

.d1 {
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
}

.d2 {
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-d) 80px,
      #0000 80px 90px,
      var(--color-d) 90px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
}

.d3 {
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-c) 75px,
      #0000 75px 95px,
      var(--color-c) 95px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-d) 80px,
      #0000 80px 90px,
      var(--color-d) 90px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
}

.d4 {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-b) 70px,
      #0000 70px 100px,
      var(--color-b) 100px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-c) 75px,
      #0000 75px 95px,
      var(--color-c) 95px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-d) 80px,
      #0000 80px 90px,
      var(--color-d) 90px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
}

.d5 {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-a) 65px,
      #0000 65px 105px,
      var(--color-a) 105px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-b) 70px,
      #0000 70px 100px,
      var(--color-b) 100px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-c) 75px,
      #0000 75px 95px,
      var(--color-c) 95px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-d) 80px,
      #0000 80px 90px,
      var(--color-d) 90px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
}

.d6 {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-d) 60px,
      #0000 60px 110px,
      var(--color-d) 110px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-a) 65px,
      #0000 65px 105px,
      var(--color-a) 105px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-b) 70px,
      #0000 70px 100px,
      var(--color-b) 100px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-c) 75px,
      #0000 75px 95px,
      var(--color-c) 95px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-d) 80px,
      #0000 80px 90px,
      var(--color-d) 90px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
}

.d7 {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-b) 10px,
      #0000 10px 160px,
      var(--color-b) 160px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-c) 15px,
      #0000 15px 155px,
      var(--color-c) 155px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-d) 20px,
      #0000 20px 150px,
      var(--color-d) 150px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-a) 25px,
      #0000 25px 145px,
      var(--color-a) 145px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-d) 60px,
      #0000 60px 110px,
      var(--color-d) 110px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-a) 65px,
      #0000 65px 105px,
      var(--color-a) 105px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-b) 70px,
      #0000 70px 100px,
      var(--color-b) 100px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-c) 75px,
      #0000 75px 95px,
      var(--color-c) 95px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      var(--color-d) 80px,
      #0000 80px 90px,
      var(--color-d) 90px
    ),
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
}
```

```html
<div class="d1"></div>
<div class="d2"></div>
<div class="d3"></div>
<div class="d4"></div>
<div class="d5"></div>
<div class="d6"></div>
<div class="d7"></div>
```

To achieve the effect you want, you need to be able to draw concentric squares. You can’t do this using linear gradients, because they are one-dimensional. The best you can do with a linear gradient is something like this.

[image]

Radial gradients are two-dimensional, but of course they are elliptical rather than rectangular. It’s possible to simulate circles (or ellipses) using radial gradients, but it’s not possible to simulate squares.

To get the effect you want, you need to use the right tool. The right tool for drawing squares is SVG. In SVG it’s easy to create squares (rectangles) with a defined stroke (border) width and no fill.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 165 165" width="165" height="165" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .st0 {stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 0px; fill: rgb(17, 85, 204);}
      .st1 {fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);}
    </style>
  </defs>
  <rect x="80" y="80" width="10" height="10" class="st0"/>
  <rect x="72.5" y="72.5" width="25" height="25" class="st1"/>
  <rect x="62.5" y="62.5" width="45" height="45" class="st1"/>
  <rect x="52.5" y="52.5" width="65" height="65" class="st1"/>
  <rect x="42.5" y="42.5" width="85" height="85" class="st1"/>
  <rect x="32.5" y="32.5" width="105" height="105" class="st1"/>
  <rect x="22.5" y="22.5" width="125" height="125" class="st1"/>
  <rect x="12.5" y="12.5" width="145" height="145" class="st1"/>
  <rect x="2.5" y="2.5" width="165" height="165" class="st1"/>
</svg>
```

[image]

You can reference an external SVG image from your style sheet, or you can [encode it into a data URL](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) which can then be embedded into your style sheet. Run this snippet for the final result.

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.d1 {
  width: 335px;
  height: 335px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 165 165' width='165' height='165' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%3E .st0 %7Bstroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 0px; fill: rgb(17, 85, 204);%7D .st1 %7Bfill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);%7D %3C/style%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Crect x='80' y='80' width='10' height='10' class='st0'/%3E%3Crect x='72.5' y='72.5' width='25' height='25' class='st1'/%3E%3Crect x='62.5' y='62.5' width='45' height='45' class='st1'/%3E%3Crect x='52.5' y='52.5' width='65' height='65' class='st1'/%3E%3Crect x='42.5' y='42.5' width='85' height='85' class='st1'/%3E%3Crect x='32.5' y='32.5' width='105' height='105' class='st1'/%3E%3Crect x='22.5' y='22.5' width='125' height='125' class='st1'/%3E%3Crect x='12.5' y='12.5' width='145' height='145' class='st1'/%3E%3Crect x='2.5' y='2.5' width='165' height='165' class='st1'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div class="d1"></div>
```

Comment: What am I supposed to do or change in my code to be able to set black to see-through and for it to work?

Comment: Is there a solution that would work like using mask-image or clip-path to make it see-through?

Comment: Would the gradient be able to be written a different way where transparent would work?

Comment: @EveNinnall the current method you are using cannot solve your problem.

Comment: @EveNinnall no, you cannot do this with gradients. You need to use SVG. I have updated my answer.

Comment: With your html code, can you show me how I can create the pattern using inline svg seen here? https://jsfiddle.net/gdq42snc/

Comment: @EveNinnall I am happy to help, but I cannot do so here. It’s a rule on Stack Overflow that we only deal with one question at a time. However, if you ask a new question I can help you there. Your new question can include a link back to this one. And once you’ve done that, add a comment here with a link to the new question. Then I can help.

Comment: @BrettDonald Can you see if you are able to help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74648364/the-svg-is-only-as-high-as-the-inner-window-but-when-you-scroll-the-window-the-s

Comment: That is something I have not figured out how to do.

Comment: Someone provided an answer, but it is not one that works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to produce such a pattern, but using pure *CSS*.

I have created two `repeating-linear-gradient` styles that are perpendicular to each other. Each shape is then clipped over its diameter.

[image] **+**
[image] **=**
[image]

The resulting shape is the same as the pattern you are looking for, but there are some limitations:

- To have a perfect pattern, the width and height should be the same to form a square.
- The result of `width`/`--w` should be an odd integer; otherwise, the result would be messed up (i.e. 105/5 = 21).

```css
.square-rep {
    --c1: #007acc;
    --c2: transparent;
    --w: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 105px; height: 105px;
}
.square-rep::after,
.square-rep::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit; height: inherit;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
        to right, var(--c1), var(--c1) var(--w), var(--c2)  var(--w), var(--c2) calc(var(--w) * 2)
    );
}
.square-rep::after {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
        to bottom, var(--c1), var(--c1) var(--w), var(--c2)  var(--w), var(--c2) calc(var(--w) * 2)
    );
}
```

```html
<div class="square-rep"></div>
<div class="square-rep" style="--w:5px"></div>
<div class="square-rep" style="--w:15px"></div>
```