# The svg is only as high as the inner window but when you scroll the window the svg scrolls with it

Tags: html, css, svg, background

The answer that was just provided doesn't work.

In the code snippet you can see clearly the svg not filling the entire viewport.

I did not think or realize this would be so hard or difficult to figure out.

The SVG are the blue boxes, and the blue boxes are supposed to cover the entire screen to the bottom, where the red is.

I am so confused, I don't understand how to have the SVG fill the entire viewport.

Red color should be behind svg, svg should be covering entire viewport

When viewed like this, red should be behind the svg.

The entire svg should be viewable.

I am not sure why the background is over the svg, or how to fix that in the code.

Is there a way to fix that in the code?

https://jsfiddle.net/6aqjxf0b/1/

How do I fix that in the code?

```
svg.in-modal {
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  top: 0; 
}
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.modal.open {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height:100%;
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: red;
}
```

html

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal open">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="blog-pager close">
            <a title="Exit" aria-label="Close"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ratio-keeper">
            <div class="wrap hide">
                    <div class="video video-frame remove" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="playInitial remove"></div>
    </div>
  <svg class="in-modal" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <use href="#box" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Code Snippet:**

[image]

```css
/*:root {
    --color-a: #1155cc;
    --color-b: transparent;
    --color-c: #1155cc;
    --color-d: transparent;
  }*/

svg {
  --color-a: red;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: red;
  --color-d: black;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
}

body:has(.modal.open) {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal.open {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height:100%;
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: red;
  /* Fallback color */
  /*background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0);*/

  /*--color-a: #1155cc;
    --color-b: transparent;
    --color-c: #1155cc;
    --color-d: transparent;



    background-image: linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
      linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-b) 10px,
        #0000 10px 160px,
        var(--color-b) 160px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-c) 15px,
        #0000 15px 155px,
        var(--color-c) 155px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-d) 20px,
        #0000 20px 150px,
        var(--color-d) 150px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-a) 25px,
        #0000 25px 145px,
        var(--color-a) 145px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-b) 30px,
        #0000 30px 140px,
        var(--color-b) 140px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-c) 35px,
        #0000 35px 135px,
        var(--color-c) 135px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-d) 40px,
        #0000 40px 130px,
        var(--color-d) 130px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-a) 45px,
        #0000 45px 125px,
        var(--color-a) 125px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-b) 50px,
        #0000 50px 120px,
        var(--color-b) 120px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-c) 55px,
        #0000 55px 115px,
        var(--color-c) 115px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-d) 60px,
        #0000 60px 110px,
        var(--color-d) 110px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-a) 65px,
        #0000 65px 105px,
        var(--color-a) 105px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-b) 70px,
        #0000 70px 100px,
        var(--color-b) 100px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-c) 75px,
        #0000 75px 95px,
        var(--color-c) 95px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-d) 80px,
        #0000 80px 90px,
        var(--color-d) 90px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
    background-size: 165px 165px;*/
}

.modal-content {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 640px;
  border: 21px solid;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  position: relative;

  padding: 1px;
}

.modal-content::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #0059dd;
  pointer-events: none;
}

:root {
  --wide: 8.8%;
  --angle1: 0;
  --angle2: -90;
}

.panel {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
      calc(var(--angle1) * 1deg),
      #ffffff00 0,
      #ffffff00 var(--wide),
      #ffffff1a calc(var(--wide) + 1px),
      #0000004d calc(var(--wide) + 2px),
      #ffffff00 calc(var(--wide) + 5px)
    ),
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      calc(calc(var(--angle2) + 90) * 1deg),
      #ffffff00 0,
      #ffffff00 var(--wide),
      #ffffff1a calc(var(--wide) + 1px),
      #0000004d calc(var(--wide) + 2px),
      #ffffff00 calc(var(--wide) + 5px)
    );
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #191919;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: 8s;
}

/*body:has(.splash-screen.hide[style]) .modal-content .panel {
    transition-delay: 4s;
    transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 1px));
  }*/

.panel.slide {
  transition-delay: 2s;
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 1px));
}

/*
  
  

All that is needed
body:has(.splash-screen.hide[style]) .modal-content .panel {
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 1px));
}

window.onload = function() {
  const splashScreen = document.querySelector('.splash-screen');
  splashScreen.classList.add('hide');
  splashScreen.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    splashScreen.style.display = 'none';
  });
};*/

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #121212;
  padding: 50px 8px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 642px;
  margin: 15px auto 30px;
  padding: 15px;
  /*box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);*/
  border: 1px solid #0059dd;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      -45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px
    );
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

/*.ratio-keeper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }*/

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.blog-pager {
  transform: translatey(100%);
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
  z-index: 1;
  /*margin: auto auto 0;*/
  pointer-events: initial;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -1px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*margin: 10px auto 0;*/
  width: 37px;
  height: 37px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*margin: auto;*/
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s ease-in;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.blog-pager.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.blog-pager::before,
.blog-pager::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.blog-pager::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.wrap.hide {
  display: none;
}

.splash-screen {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 1;
  /* Set transition duration to 1 seconds */
  pointer-events: none;
  /*dissable mouse clicking */
  cursor: default;
}

.splash-screen.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  /* Add a delay of 1 seconds before the opacity changes to 0 */
  pointer-events: none;
  /* Re-enable mouse clicking after 1 seconds */
  cursor: default;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  /*width: 50%;*/
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.panel-left.slide {
  left: 0;
}

.panel-right.slide {
  right: 0;
}

.panel-left svg, 
.panel-right svg {
  width: calc(200% - 2px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.panel-left svg {
  left: 0;
}

.panel-right svg {
  right: 0;
}


/*.panel-left::before,
  .panel-right::before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;

    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    --color-a: #1155cc;
    --color-b: transparent;
    --color-c: #1155cc;
    --color-d: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
      linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-b) 10px,
        #0000 10px 160px,
        var(--color-b) 160px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-c) 15px,
        #0000 15px 155px,
        var(--color-c) 155px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-d) 20px,
        #0000 20px 150px,
        var(--color-d) 150px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-a) 25px,
        #0000 25px 145px,
        var(--color-a) 145px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-b) 30px,
        #0000 30px 140px,
        var(--color-b) 140px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-c) 35px,
        #0000 35px 135px,
        var(--color-c) 135px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-d) 40px,
        #0000 40px 130px,
        var(--color-d) 130px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-a) 45px,
        #0000 45px 125px,
        var(--color-a) 125px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-b) 50px,
        #0000 50px 120px,
        var(--color-b) 120px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-c) 55px,
        #0000 55px 115px,
        var(--color-c) 115px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-d) 60px,
        #0000 60px 110px,
        var(--color-d) 110px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-a) 65px,
        #0000 65px 105px,
        var(--color-a) 105px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-b) 70px,
        #0000 70px 100px,
        var(--color-b) 100px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-c) 75px,
        #0000 75px 95px,
        var(--color-c) 95px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-d) 80px,
        #0000 80px 90px,
        var(--color-d) 90px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
    background-size: 165px 165px;
  }

  .panel-right::before {
    left: -100%;
  }*/

.modal:not(.open) ~ .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% - 1px));
}

.modal:not(.open) ~ .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 1px));
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.panel-right .inner {
  left: -100%;
}

.container2 {
  max-width: 360px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.container2 div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container2 img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: auto;
}

.st0 {
  stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  stroke-width: 0px;
  fill: rgb(17, 85, 204);
}

.st1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);
}

.panelsvg {
  position: fixed;
  left: -100vh;
  top: -100vh;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

svg.in-modal {
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  top: 0; 
}
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal open">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="blog-pager close">
            <a title="Exit" aria-label="Close"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ratio-keeper">
            <div class="wrap hide">
                    <div class="video video-frame remove" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="playInitial remove"></div>
    </div>
  <svg class="in-modal" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <use href="#box" />
  </svg>
</div>
<!-- end modal -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="PLYeOyMz9C9kYmnPHfw5-ItOxYBiMG4amq"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="play1"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="play2"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="play3"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="play4"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="play5" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
</div>

<div class="slide panel-left">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
        <use href="#box" />
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="slide panel-right">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
        <use href="#box" />
    </svg>
</div>

<svg class="panelsvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <g id="box">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="repeatedPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="165" height="165">
                <rect x="80" y="80" width="10" height="10" class="st0" />
                <rect x="72.5" y="72.5" width="25" height="25" class="st1" />
                <rect x="62.5" y="62.5" width="45" height="45" class="st1" />
                <rect x="52.5" y="52.5" width="65" height="65" class="st1" />
                <rect x="42.5" y="42.5" width="85" height="85" class="st1" />
                <rect x="32.5" y="32.5" width="105" height="105" class="st1" />
                <rect x="22.5" y="22.5" width="125" height="125" class="st1" />
                <rect x="12.5" y="12.5" width="145" height="145" class="st1" />
                <rect x="2.5" y="2.5" width="165" height="165" class="st1" />
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#repeatedPattern)" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Position absolute always removes the element from the layout flow. This is as per the CSS spec. Why do you need absolute? Can it be relative?

Comment: Please insert the code snippets and images directly into your post.

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate block with `overflow-y: auto;` in your modal window.

```css
/*:root {
    --color-a: #1155cc;
    --color-b: transparent;
    --color-c: #1155cc;
    --color-d: transparent;
  }*/

svg {
  --color-a: red;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: red;
  --color-d: black;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
}

body:has(.modal.open) {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal.open {
  position: fixed;
  display:block;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height:100%;
  /* overflow: auto; */
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: red;
  /* Fallback color */
  /*background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0);*/

  /*--color-a: #1155cc;
    --color-b: transparent;
    --color-c: #1155cc;
    --color-d: transparent;



    background-image: linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
      linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-b) 10px,
        #0000 10px 160px,
        var(--color-b) 160px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-c) 15px,
        #0000 15px 155px,
        var(--color-c) 155px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-d) 20px,
        #0000 20px 150px,
        var(--color-d) 150px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-a) 25px,
        #0000 25px 145px,
        var(--color-a) 145px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-b) 30px,
        #0000 30px 140px,
        var(--color-b) 140px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-c) 35px,
        #0000 35px 135px,
        var(--color-c) 135px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-d) 40px,
        #0000 40px 130px,
        var(--color-d) 130px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-a) 45px,
        #0000 45px 125px,
        var(--color-a) 125px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-b) 50px,
        #0000 50px 120px,
        var(--color-b) 120px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-c) 55px,
        #0000 55px 115px,
        var(--color-c) 115px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-d) 60px,
        #0000 60px 110px,
        var(--color-d) 110px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-a) 65px,
        #0000 65px 105px,
        var(--color-a) 105px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-b) 70px,
        #0000 70px 100px,
        var(--color-b) 100px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-c) 75px,
        #0000 75px 95px,
        var(--color-c) 95px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-d) 80px,
        #0000 80px 90px,
        var(--color-d) 90px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
    background-size: 165px 165px;*/
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 640px;
  max-width:100%;
  border: 21px solid;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal-content::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #0059dd;
  pointer-events: none;
}

:root {
  --wide: 8.8%;
  --angle1: 0;
  --angle2: -90;
}

.panel {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
      calc(var(--angle1) * 1deg),
      #ffffff00 0,
      #ffffff00 var(--wide),
      #ffffff1a calc(var(--wide) + 1px),
      #0000004d calc(var(--wide) + 2px),
      #ffffff00 calc(var(--wide) + 5px)
    ),
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      calc(calc(var(--angle2) + 90) * 1deg),
      #ffffff00 0,
      #ffffff00 var(--wide),
      #ffffff1a calc(var(--wide) + 1px),
      #0000004d calc(var(--wide) + 2px),
      #ffffff00 calc(var(--wide) + 5px)
    );
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #191919;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: 8s;
}

/*body:has(.splash-screen.hide[style]) .modal-content .panel {
    transition-delay: 4s;
    transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 1px));
  }*/

.panel.slide {
  transition-delay: 2s;
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 1px));
}

/*
  
  

All that is needed
body:has(.splash-screen.hide[style]) .modal-content .panel {
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 1px));
}

window.onload = function() {
  const splashScreen = document.querySelector('.splash-screen');
  splashScreen.classList.add('hide');
  splashScreen.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    splashScreen.style.display = 'none';
  });
};*/

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #121212;
  padding: 50px 8px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 642px;
  margin: 15px auto 30px;
  padding: 15px;
  /*box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);*/
  border: 1px solid #0059dd;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      -45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px
    );
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

/*.ratio-keeper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }*/

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.blog-pager {
  transform: translatey(100%);
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
  z-index: 1;
  /*margin: auto auto 0;*/
  pointer-events: initial;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -1px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*margin: 10px auto 0;*/
  width: 37px;
  height: 37px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*margin: auto;*/
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s ease-in;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.blog-pager.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.blog-pager::before,
.blog-pager::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.blog-pager::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.wrap.hide {
  display: none;
}

.splash-screen {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 1;
  /* Set transition duration to 1 seconds */
  pointer-events: none;
  /*dissable mouse clicking */
  cursor: default;
}

.splash-screen.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  /* Add a delay of 1 seconds before the opacity changes to 0 */
  pointer-events: none;
  /* Re-enable mouse clicking after 1 seconds */
  cursor: default;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  /*width: 50%;*/
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.panel-left.slide {
  left: 0;
}

.panel-right.slide {
  right: 0;
}

.panel-left svg, 
.panel-right svg {
  width: calc(200% - 2px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.panel-left svg {
  left: 0;
}

.panel-right svg {
  right: 0;
}


/*.panel-left::before,
  .panel-right::before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;

    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    --color-a: #1155cc;
    --color-b: transparent;
    --color-c: #1155cc;
    --color-d: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
      linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-b) 10px,
        #0000 10px 160px,
        var(--color-b) 160px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-c) 15px,
        #0000 15px 155px,
        var(--color-c) 155px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-d) 20px,
        #0000 20px 150px,
        var(--color-d) 150px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-a) 25px,
        #0000 25px 145px,
        var(--color-a) 145px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-b) 30px,
        #0000 30px 140px,
        var(--color-b) 140px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-c) 35px,
        #0000 35px 135px,
        var(--color-c) 135px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-d) 40px,
        #0000 40px 130px,
        var(--color-d) 130px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-a) 45px,
        #0000 45px 125px,
        var(--color-a) 125px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-b) 50px,
        #0000 50px 120px,
        var(--color-b) 120px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-c) 55px,
        #0000 55px 115px,
        var(--color-c) 115px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-d) 60px,
        #0000 60px 110px,
        var(--color-d) 110px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-a) 65px,
        #0000 65px 105px,
        var(--color-a) 105px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-b) 70px,
        #0000 70px 100px,
        var(--color-b) 100px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-c) 75px,
        #0000 75px 95px,
        var(--color-c) 95px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
      linear-gradient(90deg,
        var(--color-d) 80px,
        #0000 80px 90px,
        var(--color-d) 90px),
      linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
    background-size: 165px 165px;
  }

  .panel-right::before {
    left: -100%;
  }*/

.modal:not(.open) ~ .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% - 1px));
}

.modal:not(.open) ~ .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 1px));
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.panel-right .inner {
  left: -100%;
}

.container2 {
  max-width: 360px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.container2 div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container2 img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: auto;
}

.st0 {
  stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  stroke-width: 0px;
  fill: rgb(17, 85, 204);
}

.st1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);
}

.panelsvg {
  position: fixed;
  left: -100vh;
  top: -100vh;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-body{
  overflow: hidden auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

svg.in-modal {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal open">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="blog-pager close">
            <a title="Exit" aria-label="Close"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ratio-keeper">
            <div class="wrap hide">
                    <div class="video video-frame remove" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="playInitial remove"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <svg class="in-modal" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <use href="#box" />
  </svg>
</div>
<!-- end modal -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="PLYeOyMz9C9kYmnPHfw5-ItOxYBiMG4amq"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="play1"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="play2"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="play3"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="play4"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="play5" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
</div>

<div class="slide panel-left">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
        <use href="#box" />
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="slide panel-right">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
        <use href="#box" />
    </svg>
</div>

<svg class="panelsvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <g id="box">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="repeatedPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="165" height="165">
                <rect x="80" y="80" width="10" height="10" class="st0" />
                <rect x="72.5" y="72.5" width="25" height="25" class="st1" />
                <rect x="62.5" y="62.5" width="45" height="45" class="st1" />
                <rect x="52.5" y="52.5" width="65" height="65" class="st1" />
                <rect x="42.5" y="42.5" width="85" height="85" class="st1" />
                <rect x="32.5" y="32.5" width="105" height="105" class="st1" />
                <rect x="22.5" y="22.5" width="125" height="125" class="st1" />
                <rect x="12.5" y="12.5" width="145" height="145" class="st1" />
                <rect x="2.5" y="2.5" width="165" height="165" class="st1" />
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#repeatedPattern)" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: That doesn't work because that removes the right side scrollbar, and in the code snippet, it (red) is not covering the entire viewport. Red should be covering the entire thing. The scrollbar should be visible on the screen.

Comment: Image from the code snippet you provided: https://i.imgur.com/z0izY4q.png

Comment: Would you be able to fix and make corrections to it?

Comment: OK. I understood you. You need to change the modal window itself a bit. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Only one minor mistake just place SVG inside `<div class="modal-content">`
write now SVG out of this box with absolute position.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "overflow: auto;" from your ".modal.open" CSS, like this:

```
.modal.open {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    /* REMOVED: overflow: auto; */
    background-color: red;
    /* background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0); */
}
```

If it's not scrolled, you won't be seeing space below the 100%, and the SVG, which is at 100% height, will not be smaller than the visible area.

I worked on this for a day or two and this is the best solution I could find.

Comment: Doing that removes the right side scroll bar, it is needed.

Comment: Ah, so you need scrolling to work as well? I'll see what I can do.